# Retrieving orders that only contain certain product IDS

Tags: impala

I am trying to retrieve a list of transaction IDS that only contain at least 5 product IDS, the baskets could have many more product IDS but it must contain these 5 also.

My table looks something like this:

```
| transaction_id | trans_date | product_id | store_id |
```

The table is all at `product_id` line level detail, nothing is rolled up.

```
select * from Transactions
where trans_date in ('2019-03-07','2019-03-06','2019-03-08','2019-03-09','2019-03-10')
and product_id in ('000000000021003503','000000000060280873','000000000060281480','000000000060281642','000000000020059281')
```

This is recovering all the transactions that contain these ids but I need it to be rolled up to a transaction level, so if the transaction_id contained these ids (at least) then its included.

Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: Are the `trans_date` values that you are looking for unrelated to the `product_id` values that you are looking for, or does the 1st `trans_date` belong with the 1st `product_id`, etc etc? Also it would help a lot if you would give data that properly illustrates the issue (source table data + query output that you get now + query output that you would want instead).

Comment: The trans_date and product_id are unrelated.  The lines in the table are trasaction_id, date, store and product_id.  the transaction_id may repeat many times depending on how many products the customer actually bought.  What I would like to see is the transaction_id store_id and date only when the 5 product_ids are in the basket, if that makes sense.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Impala supports `GROUP BY`, `COUNT` and `HAVING`, then you can use the following.

Here we select the records for matching dates and products, then we count how many `product_id`s we actually found for each transaction on each day, and we take only those results for which we found all 5 `product_id`s.

```
SELECT transaction_id, trans_date, COUNT(product_id) as counter
FROM   Transactions
WHERE  trans_date IN ('2019-03-07','2019-03-06','2019-03-08','2019-03-09','2019-03-10')
AND    product_id IN ('000000000021003503', '000000000060280873', '000000000060281480', '000000000060281642', '000000000020059281')
GROUP BY transaction_id, trans_date
HAVING count(product_id) = 5
```

If a single transaction is allowed to span multiple dates, then you can just leave out the `trans_date` from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` parts.

Comment: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_select.html#select it's ok for `GROUP BY, COUNT and HAVING`